# How to upgrade Appium to 1.5

Tags: appium

I followed [Appium](https://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-1-5-beta-release/6058) instructions to upgrade Appium version to 1.5 . But I observed below exception when I start a server from Appium UI (Appium.exe)

```
Launching Appium server with command: D:\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --no-reset --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium --log-no-color

> module.js:338
>     throw err;
>          
^
> Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\server\main.js'
```

Before starting appium server , I checked appium version & it is still 1.4.16.1

Has anyone tried to upgrade on win 64 machine ? Please suggest if any additional setting needs to be done before upgrading / starting server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now we can download the latest version(1.7.1) from the official website.

Answer (score 1):

**Simplest way to Upgrade Appium**

- **Check** checkbox from appium settings GUI for **"Check for Updates"**
- Close **Appium GUI** and **re-launch again** OR
- You will **get a push**/pop up as **new market version released for Appium**
- **Click on upgrade pop up** and follow simple steps to upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Appium GUI does not support version 1.5 currently.

https://github.com/appium/appium-dot-exe/issues/170

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed appium using npm then you can easily upgrade appium to 1.5

Below is the command :

```
npm update -g appium
```

and if you want to upgrade to any specific version below is the command :

```
npm install -g appium@1.5.3
```

You can enter version number after '@' in the command

Answer (score 0):

Following command automatically upgrade appium , internet connection should be require,

npm install appium

Answer (score 0):

Install latest version of Node js application on windows and download and install latest version from [Appium site](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.2.7).

Check your Appium version by running Appium application.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types in Appium:
1. Appium GUI version
2. Appium Command line

1. To update appium GUI version, uninstall the older version and then download the latest version from https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases and install.
2. To update the command line version run, npm install -g appium. It will automatically take the latest version and install it.